# MVC5 LINQ display only if latest record is a certain condition

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Pardon for the unclear title, can't think of any better way to phrase it.

I have 2 tables, User and Appeal.

This is how the process works:

1. User can request to view another user's information. After
   requesting, the request will be inserted into the Appeal table with
   the **isApproved** column set to 0 by default which is *Pending*,
   and *Approved* which is 1, and *Rejected* which is 2. After a user has made the request, he will not be able to view that user as part of the list of users whom he can request to view information.
2. If the request has been Accepted OR still Pending, it should NOT show up in the list of users whom he can request to view information. **However**, if it gets rejected, it will show back up in the list so the user can somehow "re-request" it again. The condition should only be based on the LATEST request made, and not earlier requests.

The following is the statement I've came up with so far which I'm trying to achieve the above.

```
(from user in db.Users
  where user.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roleId)
  where !db.Appeal.Any(y => y.PatientId == user.Id) // if no record found in appeal
  || // or if there's a record
  (db.Appeal.OrderByDescending(a => a.Time).FirstOrDefault().PatientId == user.Id
  && db.Appeal.Any(a => a.PatientId == user.Id && a.IsApprove == 2))
  // but only if the latest request is rejected, show back up 
  // in the user list again so it can be requested again

     select new Patient {
       PatientId = user.Id,
       PatientName = user.FullName,
       UniqueId = user.UniqueId
     }).OrderBy(x => x.PatientId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the issue.

```
nameQuery = (from user in db.Users
  where user.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roleId)
  where !db.Appeal.Any(y => y.PatientId == user.Id) // if no record found in appeal
  || 
  db.Appeal.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).FirstOrDefault(p => p.PatientId 
  == user.Id).IsApprove == 2
  // or got appeal, but the latest result is rejected

  select new Patient {
   PatientId = user.Id,
   PatientName = user.FullName,
   UniqueId = user.UniqueId
   }).OrderBy(x => x.PatientId);
```

Changed

> > (db.Appeal.OrderByDescending(a => a.Time).FirstOrDefault().PatientId == user.Id
> >       && db.Appeal.Any(a => a.PatientId == user.Id && a.IsApprove == 2))

to

> > db.Appeal.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).FirstOrDefault(p => p.PatientId 
> >           == user.Id).IsApprove == 2